# Find greatest common divisor at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to find greatest common divisor at compile time with templates. Consider the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int M, int K>
class A{
public:
    static const int a=A<M,K,M%K>::a;
};
template<int N, int M>
class A<N,M,0>{
public:
    static const int a=M;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << A<11,13,11>::a;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working, but if i'm trying to write

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
template<int N, int M>
class GCD{
public:
    static const int a=A<N,M,N%M>::a;
};
template<int N, int M, int K>
class A{
public:
    static const int a=A<M,K,M%K>::a;
};
template<int N, int M>
class A<N,M,0>{
public:
    static const int a=M;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << GCD<11,13>::a;
    return 0;
}
```

I have crash error C2059 'constant'.

Why this code doesnt work?

Comment: And your question was?

Comment: My question is why it doesn work? Why i've crash?

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what line do you get it on?

Comment: Why not just use a constexpr function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a forward declaration for `A` at the top:

```
template<int N, int M, int K>
class A;
```

and then it works fine on a standard conforming compiler. Or you could just move `GCD` below all the `A` stuff.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3daf270be9c05d92)

Comment: Many thanks! But can you explain cause of this error? Why after this is works fine. I dont understand.

Comment: @St.Antario You were using `A` in `GCD` but the compiler, in this phase of translation, was just scanning the code top to bottom had no idea what `A` is, so it was giving you an error. If you forward declare it, the compiler has the required minimal knowledge to continue. I put some comments in the live example that pointed this out.